# Android studio Google plus login integration cannot get birthday

Tags: android, google-plus-signin

```
Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
String personName = person.getDisplayName();
String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
String dob = person.getBirthday();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You are Logged In " + personName+"" +email+" "+dob, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have tried this code to retrieve name email and dob but unfortunately i am not getting dob its null that i am getting.Please help

Comment: May be possible that Birthday is hidden in the profile, Like Facebook's policy for "Privacy". We can make our profile information visible to "Only Me".

Comment: Thank u .Will check that.